# Uncaught error undefined is not a function var ajax_url = $('#ajax_url').val();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeerror

I don't know what's wrong with the code, ever since we updated to PHP 5.4 I've been seeing this and the scripts aren't working.  Can someone help make this more compliant?

```
  function remove_next_step(q_id,index_number,a_id) {
    var confirm_var = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove?');
    if(confirm_var) {
        var ajax_url = $('#ajax_url').val();    
        var data = {
                    action: 'delete_next_step',
                    index_number:index_number,
                    question_number:q_id,   
                    answer_id:a_id  
                };
        jQuery.post(ajax_url, data, function(response) {         
            if(response == 1) {
                $('#row_'+q_id+"_"+index_number).remove()
                        }
                });

    }
}
```

specifically, it hates this line:

```
var ajax_url = $('#ajax_url').val();
```

Comment: You probably didn't include jQuery properly or the function is called before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Is jQuery properly included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you reference `jQuery.post` later in the sample, I'm assuming `$` is not referencing `window.jQuery` so that selector function would not be defined.

Try changing your culprit line to `var ajax_url = jQuery('#ajax_url').val();`

If that doesn't work, ensure jQuery is loaded - in the head, add this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was fixed. One of our co-developers said that this is probably due to a bigger problem associated with "NoConflict" in JS.  Does anyone know what NoConflict encompasses? If it's enabled, is it for the good (because it ensures code compliance?) Or is it better turned off because it breaks legacy (and non-compliant) code?

Comment: noConflict is just there so you can use `window.$` for something else besides jQuery. Some people use it to run multiple versions of jQuery in parallel or some other madness but that's about it.